# Handling array as form name in flask

Tags: python, flask

If I send a form like this:

```
<form method="POST" ...>
    <input type="text" name="filters[price_from]">
    <input type="text" name="filters[price_to]">
</form>
```

to PHP script it automatically creates an array and I can access variables like this:

```
$_POST['filters']['price_to']
```

and:

```
 $_POST['filters']
```

is iterable

AND this is my question, how can I get same effect in FLASK?

```
request.form.getlist('filters')
```

return [] (empty list)

```
request.form.get('filters[price_from]')
```

return right value but this is not the result of which they expect (its not iterable).

Should i rebuild my form or use some other method?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access a python array/list using a key, if you want to access your data using a key, store your `filters` as a `json` object, then you will be able to access the data by using a key.

```
<form method="POST" enctype="application/JSON">
    <input type="text" name="filters[price_from]" value="" >
    <input type="text" name="filters[price_to]" value="" >
</form>

filters = request.get_json()

filters['price_from'] #returns price_from value
filters['price_to'] #returns price_to value
```

In php an array is several things.

> An array in PHP is actually an ordered map. A map is a type that associates values to keys. This type is optimized for several different uses; it can be treated as an array, list (vector), hash table (an implementation of a map), dictionary, collection, stack, queue, and probably more.

While in python an array is **only** a [list](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) accessed by index.

```
>>> filters = ['price_from', 'price_to']
>>> filters[0]
'price_from'
>>> filters[1]
'price_to'
```

And a [dict](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) is accessed by key.

```
>>> filters = {'price_from':'value', 'price_to':'another_value'}
>>> filters['price_from']
'value'
>>> filters['price_to']
'another_value'
```

Comment: At flask 0.11.1 (Python 3.4) request.form.getlist('filters') return []. request.form.getlist('filters[]') return the same. The second way return list if the form inputs name is 'filters[]' but then I don't have key, only value.

Comment: @shinji You access a list using the index i.e. filters[0], filters[1]. To access the data by name or key i.e. filters['price_to'] you need to store it in a dict.